# Android StateFlow or MutableStateFlow in data binding

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-databinding

I'm trying out StateFlow in DataBindings and in all examples I can find, most look like a copy of [this one](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/observability#stateflow), two variables are used in the ViewModel for one data binding. One private MutableStateFlow and a public StateFlow. And the StateFlow is pretty much just reading the value from the MutableStateFlow. Why is this? Wouldn't it be easier to just have one variable, a MutableStateFlow and skip the StateFlow variable all together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a simple case of encapsulation (and is unrelated to data binding/Android). From a technical standpoint, this is a redundant step and doesn't make a difference. From a design standpoint however, it restricts modification of the `StateFlow` value outside of your containing class.

This is quite a common pattern with 'observable data holders' (`MutableLiveData` and `LiveData`), which can be thought as similar to having a property with a private setter. In fact, if you only need to collect the flow and not access its value, you could even use `Flow` as the exposed type (although as @MarkKeen pointed out, this won't work with data binding).

Comment: If using data binding you need either `LiveData<T>` or `StateFlow<T>` - these are the base types required as both allow access to the latest value on change, `Flow` does not.

Comment: Yes you're right, I'll add a caveat to my answer.